# react zoom/pan scatter plot, data filtering vs clip

Tags: reactjs, svg, large-data

I have a question in React implementation for zoom/pan function for a scatter plot.

I wonder what approach would be good and want to hear opinions of React & data visualization expert.

I am specifically interested in implementing zoom/pan function of a scatter plot that is dynamically changing data range to visualize.

(Approach 1) Given a data range (controlled by mouse wheel event), first, filter the data, and render circles () for the filtered data. In this case, each circle will be generated with new key such that

```
const circles = [];
filteredData.forEach( (d, index) => {
     circleProps = { /*..compute circle props... (e.g. position within a SVG) */ }
     circles.push(
          <circle key={`circle-${index}`} {...circleProps} />
     );
});
```

Thus, every time the data range changes, it will create new set of circles located within the range.

(Approach 2) Similar to Approach 1 but no filtering on the data. Instead, use [clip path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) to visualize only the circles within the range. In this case, it will update entire circles according to re-calculated positions but it will only create the circles one time at the beginning.

What would better approach? Or, any other options to handle large-scale data? Also, please correct me if anything is wrong.

Thanks.